# Enviar formulario con archivo a través de jQuery

Tags: jquery, formularios, archivo

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Tengo un `<div>` en el que cargo a través de ajax un formulario y proceso el formulario y quiero que muestre los datos introducidos dentro de ese `<div>`, pero algo estoy haciendo mal porque no sé como tratar los archivos subidos con jQuery.

He puesto un ejemplo con el código en Codepen, CodePen no acepta PHP, así que he tenido que adaptar el código para recibir el post con jQuery, pero la idea es utilizar PHP.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/bichomen/project/editor/AJMJkX/)

A ver si me podéis ayudar, porque me cuesta entender como jQuery trata los datos.

Código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();   

            var f = $(this, "form");
            var url = f.prop("action");

            $form = $(event.target);                
            var form = $form.serialize();               

            var files = event.target.files;                 
            var file = new FormData();

            $.each(files, function(key, value)
            {
                file.append(key, value);
            });

            alert("Datos: " + JSON.stringify(form));                
        alert("Archivo: " + JSON.stringify(file));

        $.ajax({          
           url: url,
           type: "post",              
           data: form + file,
           cache: false,
            contentType: false,
                processData: false

        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("DATA: " + JSON.stringify(data));
           $(".section").html(data);
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

`.section` es una clase de `section` en el index, donde se carga el formulario y el resultado del mismo a través de AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

// Seguir enlaces 

$("body").on("click", "a", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("href").valueOf()                     
        })                                                                                            
        .done(function(data) {

            if (data) {
                $(".section").html(data);   
        }   
            else {
                alert("Data no tiene valor");
            }           
        });
```

Comment: Buen día Isaac, podrías agregar el código directamente al foro y no como un link externo

Comment: @RandallSandoval hecho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás tratando de forma incorrecta los campos de archivos, no pueden enviarse de la manera que intentas (con `JSON.stringify()`). Debes usar [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) para ello.

Te dejo un ejemplo basado en [este gist](https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/f1ecb3c8e0b8291f2be640a7da69138b):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        var type = "post";
        var url = $(this).prop("action");
        /* Cuando mandamos sólo texto (sin archivos)
             configuramos estos valores */
        var contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        var processData = true;

        /* Para que PHP reciba todos los archivos hay que definir
             el <input> con corchetes, de modo que aquí tenemos que
             indicarlo igual */
        if (this['files[]'].files.length) {
            var data = new FormData(this);
            /* En este caso sí que hay que cambiar estos parámetros,
                 en particular contentType=false provoca una cabecera HTTP
                 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----...' */
            contentType = false;
            processData = false;
        } else {
            var data = $(this).serialize();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: type,
            contentType: contentType,
            processData: processData
        }).done(function(data) {
            $(".section").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Un ejemplo de formulario podría ser:

```
<form id="form" action="..." method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pon algo..." name="campo" /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="También aquí" name="otro" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar formulario" />
</form>
```

Es importante que si quieres usar un campo de archivos múltiples lo llames   `files[]` o cualquier otro nombre agregando `[]` para poder acceder a todos y cada uno de los archivos. En caso de que sólo permitas un campo (no tengas el atributo "multiple") entonces no es necesario, pero recuerda poner exactamente lo mismo dentro del código javascript.

Para recibir los datos en PHP podrías usar:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu .html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="archivo" name="archivo" placeholder="Archivo">
  </div>
</div>
```

En el html, tenemos un boton de la siguiente manera:

> 

El cual manda a llamar a nuestro JS de la siguiente manera:

En tu .JS

```
$("#create_documentos_modal").on('click', function() {
    $("#create_documentos_form")[0].reset();
    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    $(".message_create_documentos").html("");

    $("#create_documentos_form").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        $(".text-danger").remove();
        var form = $(this);

        var titulo = $("#titulo").val();
        var descripcion = $("#descripcion").val();
        var active = $("#active").val();
        var file2 = document.getElementById("archivo");
        var archivo = file2.files[0];

        if(titulo && descripcion && archivo && active) {

            var form = $('form')[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);

            formData.append('titulo',titulo);
            formData.append('descripcion',descripcion);
            formData.append('active',active);
            formData.append('archivo[0]',archivo);


            $.ajax({
                url : form.attr('action'),
                type : form.attr('method'),
                data : formData,
                dataType : 'json',
                success:function(response) {

                    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

                    if(response.success == true) {

                        $("#create_documentos_form")[0].reset();
                        tabla_documentos_admin.ajax.reload(null, false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Y le mandamos los datos a nuestro PHP

```
$autor=$_POST['autor'];
$titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
$descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
$active=$_POST['active'];
$namedefault = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$don=quitar_acentos($namedefault);
$nombre=str_replace(' ', '', $don);

$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$destino = "../../archivos/" . $nombre;
if ($nombre != "")
{
if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
  $sql = "INSERT INTO documentos (titulo,descripcion,tipo,active,tamano,destino,fecha,autor) VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$tipo', '$active', '$tamanio', '$nombre',NOW(),'$autor')";
  $query = $db->execute($sql);
  if($query){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Documento Almacenado","Correcto!","success");';
      echo '}, 1000);</script>';
    }
  } else { echo "Error";}
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Rastalovery

Answer (score 0):

Modificando un pelin el código de @OscarGarcia, el código que funciona es:
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
         event.preventDefault();

```
     var type = "POST";  
       var url = $(this, "form").prop("action");  
       var cache = false;
        var contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        var processData = true;     

     if(event.target.files) {           
        var data = new FormData(this);
        contentType = false;
            processData = false;
        } 
        else {
            var data = $(this).serialize();
        }

        $.ajax({
        url: url,
          data: data,
          type: type,
          cache: cache,
          contentType: contentType,
          processData: processData
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $(".section").html(data);
        }); 
    });
```

});